# CefResourceManager AddArchiveProvider failed after the browser was created

Tags: c++, chromium-embedded

i init CefResourceManager pointer in my handler class constructor,and call SetupResourceManager function immediately.

```
cefclient_handler::cefclient_handler(CefRefPtr<QCefPage> listner, CefRefPtr<CefRenderHandler> osrenderHandler)
    : is_closing_(false), clientListner_(listner), osrenderHandler_(osrenderHandler){
    resource_manager_ = new CefResourceManager();
        SetupResourceManager(resource_manager_ ,"file:///D:/test/test.zip")
}

void SetupResourceManager(CefRefPtr<CefResourceManager> resource_manager,std::string resource_dir) {
    if (!CefCurrentlyOn(TID_IO)) {
        // Execute on the browser IO thread.
        CefPostTask(TID_IO, base::Bind(SetupResourceManager, resource_manager, resource_dir));
        return;
    }
    resource_manager->AddArchiveProvider("https://***.net", resource_dir,"", 0,
        std::string());
}
```

it works well.

But in the current business needs, when the handler is initialized, the resource (zip file) is not ready, so I try to call CreateBrowser first, and then call AddArchiveProvider in my handler class when the resource file is downloaded, like this.

```
void cefclient_handler::AddArchiveProvider(const std::string& url_path, const std::string& archive_path, const std::string& password, int order, const std::string& identifier)
{
    if (!CefCurrentlyOn(TID_IO)) {
        // Execute on the browser IO thread.
        CefPostTask(TID_IO, base::Bind(&cefclient_handler::AddArchiveProvider, this, url_path, archive_path, password, order, identifier));
        return;
    }

    if (resource_manager_.get())
    {
        resource_manager_->AddArchiveProvider(url_path, archive_path, "", 0,
            std::string());
    }
}
```

It doesn't work anymore.
[image: bad result]

Comment: You'll probably have to ask on https://magpcss.org/ceforum/index.php post a link back here when you do.

Comment: Asked https://magpcss.org/ceforum/viewtopic.php?f=6&t=17120